# Snowflake Store Procedure Execute as Owner

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create an SP with execute as an owner to return a list of tables. SP was getting created but on calling it is throwing error.

```
create database trash;
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure trash.public.sandbox_tables()
  RETURNS TABLE (TABLE_SCHEMA varchar,TABLE_NAME varchar)
   LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
   EXECUTE AS OWNER
as
$$
var sql_cmd = `select TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME
      from SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.TABLES
      where TABLE_CATALOG ='SANDBOX'
      and   table_type='BASE TABLE'
      and   DELETED is NULL
      and   current_date()-CREATED::date >=90`;
var rs = snowflake.execute( {sqlText: sql_cmd} );
rs.next();
var result = rs.getColumnValue();
return result
$$;

call trash.public.sandbox_tables()
```

Error: `SQL compilation error: Invalid identifier TRASH.PUBLIC.SANDBOX_TABLES`

Not sure what was the Invalid identifier and if you could explain what is next() doing and what parameters can go into getColumnValue function/method would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures don't return tables, so I don't think it was actually created.  Here's a workaround: [Using RESULT_SCAN to Retrieve the Result from a Stored Procedure](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#using-result-scan-to-retrieve-the-result-from-a-stored-procedure)

Comment: I tried it and it's returning the return value of the call ('Done') rather than the query result.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure trash.public.sandbox_tables()
   returns varchar 
   LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
   EXECUTE AS OWNER
as
<sql
return 'Done'>
```

Comment: Ok good.  Try `SELECT * FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));` immediately after calling the stored procedure.

Comment: It's not working. It's returning the SP return value.

Comment: Ok try `SELECT * FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(-2));'   You may also have to EXECUTE AS CALLER.  IF you can't do that, a workaround is to have the proc write to a table that the caller can SELECT from.

Comment: Nope, It's not working. I tried this `select * from table(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID(-1)));`  also its not working.

Comment: What about changing to EXECUTE as CALLER?